# Find text between 2 strings globally in a file Unix

Tags: unix, design-patterns, sed, full-text-search

I have multiple .sql files containing DDLs and DMLs.

1) In one set of files there is a DDL (create table ...) followed by a DML(Merge into ....) and then again a DDL (drop table...) as below:

```
    CREATE TABLE T1 (col1 ...);
    Merge into T2 using T1.....;
    Drop table T1;
```

2) In the second set, there multiple repitions of the above pattern as:

```
    CREATE TABLE T1 (col1 ...);
    Merge into T2 using T1.....;
    CREATE TABLE T3 (col1 ...);
    Merge into T4 using T1 and T3.....;
    Drop table T1;
    Drop table T3;
```

I need to create 2 files from each source file: one with all DDLs and the other with all DMLs. I have tried sed to first search between CREATE and semicolon and direct to a DDL file, then search between Merge and semicolon and direct to DML file and finally search between Drop and semicolon and append to above DDL file.

```
    sed -n '/CREATE/,/;/p' $SRCFILE > $TGTDDLFILE
    sed -n '/Merge/,/;/p' $SRCFILE > $TGTDMLFILE
    sed -n '/Drop/,/;/p' $SRCFILE >> $TGTDDLFILE
```

It works for Set 1 but not for set 2. Is there a way I can scale it to apply to every occurence so that it covers Set 2 as well.
If not is there any other way?

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem in your original sed script is that you told sed to look for a range of lines beginning with, for example, CREATE and ending with ';' - sed doesn't consider a single line a range when you ask it to match, so it doesn't see the ';' when it is on the same line as CREATE.

Try this version and see it works better:

```
sed -ne 'H;/CREATE/h;/;/{s/.*//;x;/^CREATE/p;}' $SRCFILE > $TGTDDLFILE
```

The first command (H) puts the current line into the hold space whether we need it or not (this handles lines between CREATE and ';'). If the line contains CREATE, we overwrite the hold space with it so the line there starts with CREATE. Now if the line contains ';' we wipe out the current line and swap it with the hold space. If the hold space contents began with CREATE we print it. There's redundancy that could be cleaned up here, but at the cost of adding more to the script so I didn't bother. Unless you have have huge files it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like

```
    sed -n '/CREATE/p' $SRCFILE > $TGTDDLFILE
    sed -n '/Merge/p' $SRCFILE > $TGTDMLFILE
    sed -n '/Drop/p' $SRCFILE >> $TGTDDLFILE
```

This will do what you are looking for provided that the files you are referring to have one SQL statement on one line. It will fail both in case of multiple SQL statements on one line and one SQL statement on multiple lines.

If this be the case, you may also use `grep`.

```
    cat $SRCFILE | grep 'CREATE' > $TGTDDLFILE
    cat $SRCFILE | grep 'Merge' > $TGTDMLFILE
    cat $SRCFILE | grep 'Drop' >> $TGTDDLFILE
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this does not help. Sorry, I forgot to mention that one sql is spanned across multiple lines. When I used grep, it output just the CREATE TABLE <tablename> twice but with different tablenames. I tried to take it one step further using the output from grep in a for loop var and sed -n /$var/,/; $SRCFILE but it didnt work